# How to update path coordinates in a svg image swift

Tags: swift, svg, calayer, cashapelayer, pocketsvg

I have a svg image, when i touch the image i get the shapeLayer selected and I change its color but when i transform the image to move it in the device i need to touch the original position to detect the shapeLayer. I'm using PocketSVG.

This is my code:

```
let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleTap(_:)))
view.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)
view.isUserInteractionEnabled = true

svgView = SVGImageView.init(contentsOf: svgURl)
    
paths = SVGBezierPath.pathsFromSVG(at: svgURl)
    
for (index, path) in paths.enumerated() {
    let shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    shapeLayer.path = path.cgPath
    shapeLayer.fillColor = colors[index].cgColor
    gamerCat.addSublayer(shapeLayer)}
    
    
var transform = CATransform3DMakeScale(0.4, 0.4, 1.0)
transform = CATransform3DTranslate(transform, 200, 400, 0)
gamerCat.transform = transform

gamerCat.shouldRasterize = false
    
svgView.layer.addSublayer(gamerCat)

view.addSubview(svgView)

@objc func handleTap(_ gesture: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    print("-----------------------------------")
    let location = gesture.location(in: view)
    print("Location : \(location)")
    rects.removeAll(keepingCapacity: false)
    indiceRect.removeAll(keepingCapacity: false)
    elementTouched(location: location)
        
}

    
func elementTouched(location:CGPoint) {
    let shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    for (index, path) in paths.enumerated() {
    shapeLayer.path = path.cgPath
            
    isRectContained(rectA: shapeLayer.path!.boundingBox, rectB: CGRect(x: location.x, y: location.y, width: 1, height: 1), index: index)
            
    }
        
    var smallestRect = rects.first
        
    for rect in rects.dropFirst() {
        if let currentSmallest = smallestRect {
            if rect.width * rect.height < currentSmallest.width * currentSmallest.height {
                smallestRect = rect
            }
        } else {
            smallestRect = rect
        }
    }
        
    if let smallestRect = smallestRect {
        print("El CGRect más pequeño es: \(smallestRect)")
        var elegido = indiceRect[rects.firstIndex(of: smallestRect)!]
        shapeLayer.path = paths[elegido].cgPath
        shapeLayer.fillColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
            
    } else {
        print("Array is empty.")
    }
        
    gamerCat.addSublayer(shapeLayer)
}
```

This is what I do, I don't know if I need to make a transform to move the image. I tried to move with svgView.frame but the size of the image don't change and i tried to use clips.blouns but my image disappear

Comment: The `SVGImageView` uses layers for each "shape" in the SVG file. I'm assuming what you mean is you want to manipulate an individual shape layer? Start with a **very simple** SVG file... edit your question to include that file (it is plain text), and also provide ***minimal but complete code*** that we can copy/paste and run to help you.